# Display element based on data from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a step by step form. I'm using AngularJS and UI-router to display the different forms, the value from these are stored in a javascript array. Since the element isn't active I'm trying to evaluate the data to show or hide a div.

The data is stored in:

```
$scope.formData = {};
```

Which is populated (among others) from this;

```
<input type="checkbox" id="outGoingEmail" onclick="showMe('outGoingEmail')" name="outGoingEmailChk" ng-model="formData.outEmail">
```

By dumping the data I can see that it evaluates to true;

```
<pre>
    {{ formData }}
</pre>

 {"outEmail":true}
```

I'm new to javascript but I've tried a lot of things but my div is always displayed:

```
<div id="incSMS">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.incSMSNumber">
</div>
```

The JS I've got so far;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(outEmail == true) {
        document.getElementById("incSMS").style.display = 'block'; 
    }else {
        document.getElementById("incSMS").style.display = 'none'; 
    }
});
```

How do I evaluate outEmail properly?

Comment: I see that you use angularjs and pure js? Is this JS code in a angular controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do couple of things with angular you can try ng-if or ng-show:

```
<div ng-if="!formData"></div>
```

It wil hide the div element if formData doesn't exist. Good luck!

Read more about it at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Glad it helped :). If you are playing with angular try to avoid jquery and try to do it the angular way. It's much easier.